# Testing if measurement comes from complex distribution (uniform plus normal)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I want test if measurement comes from my reference. I know reference distribution, for example it is:

$$
X = f(A,B)  \\
A \sim N(0, \sigma) \\
B \sim U(a,b) \\
$$
$ f(A,B) $ - some function of the variables, for example $ f(A,B) = A + B $

Then I can run Monte Carlo (MC) simulation to simulate my distribution.
On picture below you can see simulated distribution as blue line.

From the other hand I can simulate two distributions:
$$
X_{l}  = f(A,a)  \\
X_{u}  = f(A,b) \\
$$
Where $ a,b $ are lower and uper limit of uniform distribution

If I want test if I can reject that measurement $x_m$ comes from reference distribution then I am not sure how to construct critical region in first case (from $X$).
In second case when I have  say uper and lower limit distribution and then I can construct one-tiled uper bound $X_{l}$ distribution and one-tiled lower bound for $X_{u}$. then I assume that p-value of the test can be calculated as sum p-values of uper and lower limit test variables:
$$
p = p_u + p_l
$$ 
From the other hand maybe I can construct two tailed critical region for $X$ distribution where one tail is limited by $x_m$ and the second is limited by symmetric quantile. But in this case this test will produce lower p-values than bounduary test. 
In the example below it's quite natural for me that I do not want to reject $x_m = 1$ I am most intreated in case if I can reject $x_m = -0.1$ or  $x_m = 4.3$ so the bounduary test is in this case seems to be more resonable. Moreover to test my measurement against $X$ test variable I think that I have to generate much more Monte Carlo samples than in bounduary case. In fact for bounduary test in this case i do not even have to use MC.

What do you think about this?
Do you have any reference where I can read about this problem?
Can I somehow evaluate performance of this two tests (reference MC and Bounduary)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to simulate, this distribution has a closed-form solution!

If $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$ and $U \sim \mathcal{U}(a,b)$, then $Z+U$ follows a distribution described by Bhattacharjee, Pandit, and Mohan (1963), that has probability density function

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2a} \left[\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu+a}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu-a}{\sigma}\right)\right]
$$

and cumulative distribution function

$$
F(x) = \frac{\sigma}{2a} \left[(x-\mu)\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu+a}{\sigma}\right) -
                                (x-\mu)\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu-a}{\sigma}\right) +
                                \phi\left(\frac{x-\mu+a}{\sigma}\right) -
                                \phi\left(\frac{x-\mu-a}{\sigma}\right)\right]
$$

where $\Phi$ is standard normal cdf and $\phi$ is standard normal pdf.

In R you can find it's implementation (pdf, cdf and random generation) in [extraDistr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=extraDistr) package.

> Bhattacharjee, G.P., Pandit, S.N.N., and Mohan, R. (1963). Dimensional
>   chains involving rectangular and normal error-distributions.
>   Technometrics, 5, 404-406.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact I have more complicated distirbution than $Z + U$. 

The question was more related to what is the concequences of testing my hypothesis using 'bounduary test' instead of lest say 'clasic one'.